# Statistical test on likert and ranking data

Tags: statistical-significance, likert, ranking

I have data in which survey participants hand to rank (Rank 1 to 3) three specific products.
They also answered some 5 point Likert scale questions (from 1: “Strongly Agree” to 5:“Strongly disagree”) to each product.
Now I want to (statistically) test if any of these questions had impact on their ranking.
Unfortunately, I do not know which test is suitable for this task.

May data looks like this:

Ranking of the participants

```
               A               B              C 
Rank 1        26               9             15
Rank 2        13              15             22
Rank 3        11              26             13
```

Answers to one question

```
   1  2  3  4  5 
Q1 4  7  8 22  9
```

## ===EDIT 1

I transformed my data into long format (part = the participant; rank = the ranking of the choice; choice=the product; qn= answer to question n)

```
                 part   rank     choice   q1 q2 q3
    1             1       1         P1    2  4  4
    2             1       2         P2    2  4  4
    3             1       3         P3    2  4  4
    4             2       1         P1    5  4  5
    5             2       2         P2    5  4  5
    6             2       3         P3    5  4  5
    7             3       1         P1    4  4  4
    8             3       2         P2    4  4  4
    9             3       3         P3    4  4  4
```

Now I would like to see if there is a statistically significant correlation with the *choices* and the resposnes to *q1-3*. But I do not know who to do that.
I cannot use the the `lm` function in R (e.g., choice~q1) because *choice* is a factor.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have all the data points or do you only have aggregates such as in the tables above?

Comment: I do have all the data points

Comment: Maybe a linear model could be used, you would have to reshape your data into long format.

Comment: @user2974951 see my edit of the original question. How can I use this data in a linear model?